# ListViews within ScrollView overlaps my TextViews

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

I've seen a lot of problem related to mine, however, none of those have worked. I am currently designing a view where I have four ListViews within a ScrollView, and I want to make the whole ScrollView scroll, while all items in the ListViews are showing. That is no problem; however, the listviews keep overlapping my headertexts for the different listviews.

I've tried with both margins and paddings; none of which whom work. I've also tried to remake the scrollLayout into a LinearLayout. I've also tried to put the texts within separate LinearLayouts, separated from the ListViews, but that does not work either.

Below is my src code. Does anyone know how to make the text to not overlap with the Top item in the listViews? Btw, the "Top Result", the one up above, works totally fine.

> 

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/topResultLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topResultTitle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topResultList"
                android:layout_below="@id/topResultTitle"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/streamResultLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/topResultLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/streamResultTitle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seeAllStreams"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/streamResultList" />





            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/streamResultList"
                android:layout_below="@id/streamResultTitle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/broadcasterResultLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/streamResultLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/broadcasterResultTitle"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"

                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seeAllBroadcasters"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />




            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/broadcasterResultList"
                android:layout_below="@id/broadcasterResultTitle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/tagResultLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/broadcasterResultLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tagResultTitle"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seeAllTags"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />




            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tagResultList"
                android:layout_below="@id/tagResultTitle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Never use `ListView` inside `ScrollView` and vice-versa

Comment: listview itself a scroll kinda view

Comment: Well looks fine xml wise I think, what are you using to expand it? I use the code below.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView, ListAdapter adapter)
    {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = adapter;

        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0) {
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work like a charm. Still some problems however. It only shows one out of three items of the first ListView, the streamResultList. Do you perhaps know what causes that? Also, the last still did not work, so I added a padding top of 20dp, and the TextViews and the ListView within the tagResultLayout got separated. However, a small part of the last item in tagResultList vanished. Can I add some space within the ListView in your function? perhaps in the loop, something like if (i == listAdapter.getCount()) ?

Comment: I fixed the first problem now, so I see all the streams. However it still does not work to click on seeAll in the last section. The padding makes it impossible to click on it unfortunatley, even though the padding fixes the layout issue. Do you know how to fix that? Thank you very very much for your help btw!